# How to create address fields in Google Contacts using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

The whole address is going in the address field, nothing is going in the city, st, zip code fields, etc.

```
var addRess = streetAdd + ", " + city + ", " + state + " " + zipCode;
contact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS, addRess);
```

Comment: Please, provide us with info on how `streetAdd`, `city`, `state` and `zipCode` are assigned, most likely there is an issue with how formatted address string is constructed

Answer (score 2):

- You want to add each value to the city, st, zip code fields to the contact as an address using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

In this answer, People API is used. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the methods for adding each value to the city, st, zip code fields in [Contacts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts). So I used the methods of people.connections.list and people.updateContact in People API for achieving your goal.

Before you use this script, **[please enable People API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)**

### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows. And please set the variables of `streetAdd`, `city`, `state` and `zipCode`. I thought that `state` might be `region`. About this, if my understanding is not correct, I apologize. If you want to set other fields, please check [the document of Address](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#address).

#### From:

```
var addRess = streetAdd + ", " + city + ", " + state + " " + zipCode;
contact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS, addRess);
```

#### To:

```
var streetAdd = "###";
var city = "###";
var state = "###";
var zipCode = "###";

var addAddress = {
  streetAddress: streetAdd,
  city: city,
  region: state,
  postalCode: zipCode
};
var id = contact.getId().split("/").pop();
var list = People.People.Connections.list("people/me", {personFields: "addresses,emailAddresses"});
var contact = list.connections.filter(function(connection) {
  return connection.emailAddresses.filter(function(email) {
    return email.metadata.source.id == id;
  }).length > 0;
})[0];
var resource = {
  addresses: "addresses" in contact ? contact.addresses.concat([addAddress]) : addAddress,
  etag: contact.etag
};
People.People.updateContact(resource, contact.resourceName, {updatePersonFields: "addresses"});
```

- When this script is run, new address is added to `contact` like `contact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS, addRess)`.

### Note:

- This modified script supposed that `contact` in your script has already been declared and been able to be used as the contact object.

### References:

- [Contacts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)
- [Method: people.updateContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact)
- [Address](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#address)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.